# Integer Triangles with Perimeter $n$

Tags: combinatorics, triangles

> > How many triangles are possible with positive integer side lengths for perimeter $n$?

My attempt so far has been bashing for $n=1,\; 2, \cdots , 13$ and calculating how many triangles are possible for those specific $n$'s. I found a pattern for when $n$ is odd or even, but haven't really been able to do much more than that.

I think I it would be useful to assume for a triangle $\left ( a,b,c\right )$ that $$ a \leq  b \leq c$$ to avoid over counting.

Comment: Hint: Assuming $a \leq b \leq c$, a triangle of side lengths $(a,b,c)$ exists iff $a+b \geq c$.

Comment: Excluding flat triangles and using your convention, all triples such that $a+b>c$ are possible. With $a+b+c=n$, this gives $2(a+b)>n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Let $a,b,c$ denote the lengths of the sides of the triangle. Then we should have
$$a+b>c\quad\mbox{and}\quad a+b+c=n.$$
The above two equations implies $a+b-c=n-2c>0$, i.e. $c<n/2$ and similarly $a,b<n/2$. So you need to count the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $0<a\leq b\leq c$ and $a,b,c<n/2$.

EDIT: Note that you only need to find the number of tuples $(a,b)$ such that $0<a\leq b$ and $a,b<n/2$, because $c$ is fixed once you specify $a$ and $b$. Let us consider two cases.

Case (i) $n$ is even: For a fixed $a$, you have the following choices for $b$: $a+1, a+2,\cdots ,n/2-1$, that is $n/2-1-a$ choices. Now $a$ can take values $1,2,\ldots ,n/2-1$. So the number of triangles in this case is
$$\sum_{a=1}^{n/2-1}(n/2-1-a)=(n/2-2)+(n/2-3)+\cdots +1=\frac{(n/2-2)(n/2-1)}{2}.$$

Case (ii) $n$ is odd: For a fixed $a$, you have the following choices for $b$: $a+1, a+2,\cdots ,(n-1)/2$, that is $(n-1)/2-a$ choices. Now $a$ can take values $1,2,\ldots ,(n-1)/2$. So the number of triangles in this case is
$$\sum_{a=1}^{(n-1)/2}((n-1)/2-a)=((n-1)/2-1)+\cdots +1=\frac{((n-1)/2-1)(n-1)/2}{2}.$$

Comment: excluding 0. You would want to add that :)

Comment: I think that should be obvious, length of a line segment can not be $0$; anyway, specified.

Comment: Obvious, yes. But it's easy to miss while forming the expressions, at least to me.

Comment: @pritam I still haven't been able to fully solve it. Do you mind showing the solution? I'm apparently supposed to arrive at Alcuin's Sequence, but i'm not sure how I would have ever formed that sequence myself.

Comment: @Ozera: Fix $a=x$, then choices for $b$ are $x+1, x+2,\ldots ,[n/2]$, i.e. $[n/2]-x$ choices and there are $[n/2]$ choices for $a$. Note that $c$ is fixed once you specify $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @pritam Would it suffice for answer to find the number of triangles for when $n$ is odd or even?

Comment: @Ozera: Yes, you can consider odd and even case separately if you don't want to use $[\cdot]$ notation.

Comment: @pritam Well, I found that bashing was easy and was able to create a function for n even and n odd. Though, I don't like it since it's not really a combinatorial proof. Your hint is for the combo proof, but I don't understand how to do it unfortunately.

Comment: @Ozera: I have completed the answer, have a look.

Comment: Very nice! I decided to give our math camp students this probem for our math "Team-Contest" for next Sunday, but for $n = 48$. 50 problems, 90 minutes.

Comment: This does not seem correct to me. In case $n=9$ for example your formula yields $6$ triangles, while there are actually only $3$.

Comment: i think this is wrong. is it not standard honsberger result

Answer (score 3):

A bit of looking up gives the sequence [A005044](http://oeis.org/A005044)

Also, this [paper](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper98.pdf) might be of interest.

Comment: A few more references for [alucin](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlcuinsSequence.html)'s sequence: [1.](http://www.jamestanton.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Integer-Triangles_Sample-Book-Chapter_Math-Galore.pdf) A simple closed form by elementary means [2.](http://www2.edc.org/makingmath/handbook/Teacher/GettingInformation/TrianglesAndBarrels.pdf) Triangles with Integer Sides and Sharing Barrels

Comment: Thanks for the references.